# How can i release only the builds that have a specific Tag?

Tags: azure, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a release with several artifacts and several stages. The thing is that I am trying to make a conditional, so that only the artifacts that have a certain tag are deployed.

In my case, the tag that I put to the builds is date and hours : `$(Date:yyyyMMdd)`

And the condition is the following:

```
 and(succeeded(), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'refs/tags/variables[tag]'))
```

Where the `variable [tag]` is manually changed according to the day.I deploy only once a day, so this kind of tag is useful to me, since I can use it as a variable and change the `variable [tag]` every day that I have to deploy.

The error I have is that the condition does not work.

If I create the tag in the build that, for example is `20221011 (Date:yyyyMMdd)` but when I release the artifact, it skips the release, when it would not be the case, because the `variable of my [tag]` I have set it, manually as `"20221011"`. Which is the same value as the tag that i have on the build.

What am I doing wrong ?

The error I have is as follows :

```
Evaluating: and(succeeded(), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'refs/tags/20221011')) Expanded: and(True, startsWith('develop', 'refs/tags/20221011')) Result: False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write a YAML for you, it can check whether pipeline run based on tag, and check whether the tag matches datetime format.

```
# trigger:
# - none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
variables:
  # matchTag: $[startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')]
  isTag: $[startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/')]
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host "Main step."
      Write-Host $(Build.SourceBranch)
      Write-Host $(isTag)
      # xxx #This will skip the continue step.
- task: PowerShell@2
  name: check_datetime_format
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host "Continue step."
      $str = "$(Build.SourceBranch)"
      #get the string after refs/tags/
      $tag = $str.Substring(10)
      $format = "yyyyMMdd"
      Write-Host $tag
      try {
          [DateTime]::ParseExact($tag, $format, $null)
          Write-Host "The datetime is correct"
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=matchTime]true"
      }
      catch {
          Write-Host "The datetime is not correct."
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=matchTime]false"
      }
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.isTag, 'true'))
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Write your PowerShell commands here.
      
      Write-Host $(matchTime)
- task: PowerShell@2
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.matchTime, 'true'))
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Write your PowerShell commands here.
      
      Write-Host "The format is correct."
```

If you want solution for release pipeline for DevOps feature concept, then save the following data to a .json file, and then import it:

```
{
    "source": 2,
    "revision": 10,
    "description": null,
    "isDeleted": false,
    "variables": {
        "isTag": {
            "value": "$[startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/')]"
        }
    },
    "variableGroups": [],
    "environments": [
        {
            "id": 13,
            "name": "Stage 1",
            "rank": 1,
            "owner": {
                "displayName": "Bowman Zhu",
                "url": "https://spsprodsea2.vssps.visualstudio.com/A64545e3d-c12d-4c81-b77f-4de83783d9bd/_apis/Identities/af91e22a-cc35-4c8e-8af3-f49c4a1b9b6a",
                "_links": {
                    "avatar": {
                        "href": "https://dev.azure.com/BowmanCP/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/aad.ZGU3N2NiY2YtZTgzYy03ZDkwLWI0YTYtOTk3Nzg3NDczMzBl"
                    }
                },
                "id": "af91e22a-cc35-4c8e-8af3-f49c4a1b9b6a",
                "uniqueName": "xxx@163.com",
                "imageUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/BowmanCP/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/aad.ZGU3N2NiY2YtZTgzYy03ZDkwLWI0YTYtOTk3Nzg3NDczMzBl",
                "descriptor": "aad.ZGU3N2NiY2YtZTgzYy03ZDkwLWI0YTYtOTk3Nzg3NDczMzBl"
            },
            "variables": {},
            "variableGroups": [],
            "preDeployApprovals": {
                "approvals": [
                    {
                        "rank": 1,
                        "isAutomated": true,
                        "isNotificationOn": false,
                        "id": 37
                    }
                ],
                "approvalOptions": {
                    "requiredApproverCount": null,
                    "releaseCreatorCanBeApprover": false,
                    "autoTriggeredAndPreviousEnvironmentApprovedCanBeSkipped": false,
                    "enforceIdentityRevalidation": false,
                    "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
                    "executionOrder": 1
                }
            },
            "deployStep": {
                "id": 38
            },
            "postDeployApprovals": {
                "approvals": [
                    {
                        "rank": 1,
                        "isAutomated": true,
                        "isNotificationOn": false,
                        "id": 39
                    }
                ],
                "approvalOptions": {
                    "requiredApproverCount": null,
                    "releaseCreatorCanBeApprover": false,
                    "autoTriggeredAndPreviousEnvironmentApprovedCanBeSkipped": false,
                    "enforceIdentityRevalidation": false,
                    "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
                    "executionOrder": 2
                }
            },
            "deployPhases": [
                {
                    "deploymentInput": {
                        "parallelExecution": {
                            "parallelExecutionType": 0
                        },
                        "agentSpecification": null,
                        "skipArtifactsDownload": false,
                        "artifactsDownloadInput": {
                            "downloadInputs": []
                        },
                        "queueId": 13,
                        "demands": [],
                        "enableAccessToken": false,
                        "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
                        "jobCancelTimeoutInMinutes": 1,
                        "condition": "succeeded()",
                        "overrideInputs": {}
                    },
                    "rank": 1,
                    "phaseType": 1,
                    "name": "Agent job",
                    "refName": null,
                    "workflowTasks": [
                        {
                            "environment": {},
                            "taskId": "e213ff0f-5d5c-4791-802d-52ea3e7be1f1",
                            "version": "2.*",
                            "name": "PowerShell Script",
                            "refName": "",
                            "enabled": true,
                            "alwaysRun": false,
                            "continueOnError": false,
                            "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
                            "retryCountOnTaskFailure": 0,
                            "definitionType": "task",
                            "overrideInputs": {},
                            "condition": "succeeded()",
                            "inputs": {
                                "targetType": "inline",
                                "filePath": "",
                                "arguments": "",
                                "script": "Write-Host \"Main step.\"\nWrite-Host $(Build.SourceBranch)\nWrite-Host $(isTag)",
                                "errorActionPreference": "stop",
                                "warningPreference": "default",
                                "informationPreference": "default",
                                "verbosePreference": "default",
                                "debugPreference": "default",
                                "progressPreference": "silentlyContinue",
                                "failOnStderr": "false",
                                "showWarnings": "false",
                                "ignoreLASTEXITCODE": "false",
                                "pwsh": "false",
                                "workingDirectory": "",
                                "runScriptInSeparateScope": "false"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "environment": {},
                            "taskId": "e213ff0f-5d5c-4791-802d-52ea3e7be1f1",
                            "version": "2.*",
                            "name": "PowerShell Script",
                            "refName": "",
                            "enabled": true,
                            "alwaysRun": false,
                            "continueOnError": false,
                            "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
                            "retryCountOnTaskFailure": 0,
                            "definitionType": "task",
                            "overrideInputs": {},
                            "condition": "and(succeeded(), eq(variables.isTag, 'true'))",
                            "inputs": {
                                "targetType": "inline",
                                "filePath": "",
                                "arguments": "",
                                "script": "Write-Host \"Continue step.\"\n$str = \"$(Build.SourceBranch)\"\n#get the string after refs/tags/\n$tag = $str.Substring(10)\n$format = \"yyyyMMdd\"\nWrite-Host $tag\ntry {\n    [DateTime]::ParseExact($tag, $format, $null)\n    Write-Host \"The datetime is correct\"\n    Write-Host \"##vso[task.setvariable variable=matchTime]true\"\n}\ncatch {\n    Write-Host \"The datetime is not correct.\"\n    Write-Host \"##vso[task.setvariable variable=matchTime]false\"\n}",
                                "errorActionPreference": "stop",
                                "warningPreference": "default",
                                "informationPreference": "default",
                                "verbosePreference": "default",
                                "debugPreference": "default",
                                "progressPreference": "silentlyContinue",
                                "failOnStderr": "false",
                                "showWarnings": "false",
                                "ignoreLASTEXITCODE": "false",
                                "pwsh": "false",
                                "workingDirectory": "",
                                "runScriptInSeparateScope": "false"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "environment": {},
                            "taskId": "e213ff0f-5d5c-4791-802d-52ea3e7be1f1",
                            "version": "2.*",
                            "name": "PowerShell Script",
                            "refName": "",
                            "enabled": true,
                            "alwaysRun": false,
                            "continueOnError": false,
                            "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
                            "retryCountOnTaskFailure": 0,
                            "definitionType": "task",
                            "overrideInputs": {},
                            "condition": "succeeded()",
                            "inputs": {
                                "targetType": "inline",
                                "filePath": "",
                                "arguments": "",
                                "script": "Write-Host $(matchTime)",
                                "errorActionPreference": "stop",
                                "warningPreference": "default",
                                "informationPreference": "default",
                                "verbosePreference": "default",
                                "debugPreference": "default",
                                "progressPreference": "silentlyContinue",
                                "failOnStderr": "false",
                                "showWarnings": "false",
                                "ignoreLASTEXITCODE": "false",
                                "pwsh": "false",
                                "workingDirectory": "",
                                "runScriptInSeparateScope": "false"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "environment": {},
                            "taskId": "e213ff0f-5d5c-4791-802d-52ea3e7be1f1",
                            "version": "2.*",
                            "name": "PowerShell Script",
                            "refName": "",
                            "enabled": true,
                            "alwaysRun": false,
                            "continueOnError": false,
                            "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
                            "retryCountOnTaskFailure": 0,
                            "definitionType": "task",
                            "overrideInputs": {},
                            "condition": "and(succeeded(), eq(variables.matchTime, 'true'))",
                            "inputs": {
                                "targetType": "inline",
                                "filePath": "",
                                "arguments": "",
                                "script": "Write-Host \"The format is correct.\"",
                                "errorActionPreference": "stop",
                                "warningPreference": "default",
                                "informationPreference": "default",
                                "verbosePreference": "default",
                                "debugPreference": "default",
                                "progressPreference": "silentlyContinue",
                                "failOnStderr": "false",
                                "showWarnings": "false",
                                "ignoreLASTEXITCODE": "false",
                                "pwsh": "false",
                                "workingDirectory": "",
                                "runScriptInSeparateScope": "false"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "environmentOptions": {
                "emailNotificationType": "OnlyOnFailure",
                "emailRecipients": "release.environment.owner;release.creator",
                "skipArtifactsDownload": false,
                "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
                "enableAccessToken": false,
                "publishDeploymentStatus": true,
                "badgeEnabled": false,
                "autoLinkWorkItems": false,
                "pullRequestDeploymentEnabled": false
            },
            "demands": [],
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "name": "ReleaseStarted",
                    "conditionType": 1,
                    "value": ""
                }
            ],
            "executionPolicy": {
                "concurrencyCount": 1,
                "queueDepthCount": 0
            },
            "schedules": [],
            "currentRelease": {
                "id": 55,
                "url": "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/BowmanCP/c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6/_apis/Release/releases/55",
                "_links": {}
            },
            "retentionPolicy": {
                "daysToKeep": 30,
                "releasesToKeep": 3,
                "retainBuild": true
            },
            "processParameters": {},
            "properties": {
                "BoardsEnvironmentType": {
                    "$type": "System.String",
                    "$value": "unmapped"
                },
                "LinkBoardsWorkItems": {
                    "$type": "System.String",
                    "$value": "False"
                }
            },
            "preDeploymentGates": {
                "id": 0,
                "gatesOptions": null,
                "gates": []
            },
            "postDeploymentGates": {
                "id": 0,
                "gatesOptions": null,
                "gates": []
            },
            "environmentTriggers": [],
            "badgeUrl": "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/BowmanCP/_apis/public/Release/badge/c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6/13/13"
        }
    ],
    "artifacts": [
        {
            "sourceId": "c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6:324",
            "type": "Build",
            "alias": "_Test_Tag_Trigger",
            "definitionReference": {
                "defaultVersionBranch": {
                    "id": "",
                    "name": ""
                },
                "defaultVersionSpecific": {
                    "id": "",
                    "name": ""
                },
                "defaultVersionTags": {
                    "id": "20220104",
                    "name": "20220104"
                },
                "defaultVersionType": {
                    "id": "latestWithBuildDefinitionBranchAndTagsType",
                    "name": "Latest from the build pipeline default branch with tags"
                },
                "definition": {
                    "id": "324",
                    "name": "Test_Tag_Trigger"
                },
                "definitions": {
                    "id": "",
                    "name": ""
                },
                "IsMultiDefinitionType": {
                    "id": "False",
                    "name": "False"
                },
                "project": {
                    "id": "c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6",
                    "name": "BowmanCP"
                },
                "repository": {
                    "id": "",
                    "name": ""
                },
                "artifactSourceDefinitionUrl": {
                    "id": "https://dev.azure.com/BowmanCP/_permalink/_build/index?collectionId=b1cc953d-b564-4eec-a222-84393e4406b1&projectId=c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6&definitionId=324",
                    "name": ""
                }
            },
            "isPrimary": true,
            "isRetained": false
        }
    ],
    "triggers": [],
    "releaseNameFormat": "Release-$(rev:r)",
    "tags": [],
    "properties": {
        "DefinitionCreationSource": {
            "$type": "System.String",
            "$value": "ReleaseNew"
        },
        "IntegrateBoardsWorkItems": {
            "$type": "System.String",
            "$value": "False"
        },
        "IntegrateJiraWorkItems": {
            "$type": "System.String",
            "$value": "false"
        }
    },
    "id": 13,
    "name": "Test_Tag_Trigger",
    "path": "\\",
    "projectReference": null,
    "url": "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/BowmanCP/c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6/_apis/Release/definitions/13",
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/BowmanCP/c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6/_apis/Release/definitions/13"
        },
        "web": {
            "href": "https://dev.azure.com/BowmanCP/c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6/_release?definitionId=13"
        }
    }
}
```

You can check the configuration on my side, and write your own release pipeline based on it.

In my situation, if the source is based on tag such as '20220104'(match the datetime format), my PowerShell script will judge whether the tag matches the datetime format, and then judge whether do the next operations.

By the way, in release pipeline of DevOps concept, it is impossible to set the git repo as the source and select the tag. Only based on build artifact can achieve this(select the tag).

***If the condition passed:***

[image]

***If the condition didn't pass:***

[image]

The logic of the JSON data is basically the same as the YAML, for your situation, I think the YAML pipeline can also be a 'release pipeline'(The actual functionality is a release, but it doesn't use the release pipeline provided by DevOps.).

Comment: But how can i add this to my release? How can i use this script on my release? On the pipeline I add the tag with the option "Tag Sources", and the value is $(Date:yyyyMMdd) . So if in my release, the artifact has the tag $(Date:yyyyMMdd) that artifact should be released, and the ones who dont have it, will not be released, just skipped.

Comment: @EduardFTW Is the release you mentioned means DevOps release pipeline?

Comment: @EduardFTW I update the answer with the JSON file of release pipeline.

Comment: This is awsome, thank you very much!